# Adding Simple Progress Bar while inserting Data to SQL Server in C# windows form

Tags: c#, sql-server, progress-bar

I need to add a simple progress bar while inserting some data to a sql server database. my code works to insert data but I need to add progress bar showing progress while inserting that data from start to end. So I am not sure how to start to add the progress bar and end it. Any advice would be greatly appreciated

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using PasswordLogs.Data;

namespace PasswordLogs
{

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private readonly CurrentUser _currentUserOnApp = new CurrentUser();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GetDataInformation();
        InsertDataToDb();
    }

    private void Button_Clear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Clear();
    }

    public void GetDataInformation()
    {

        try
        {
            if (Combo_ServiceType.SelectedItem == null && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Text_Username.Text) && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Text_Password.Text) && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Text_OldPassword.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show(@"(Service Type, Username, Password, Old Password) cannot be null or empty", @"User Information", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        Text_OldPassword.Clear();
        Text_Password.Clear();
        Text_Description.Clear();
        Text_Notes.Clear();
        Text_Username.Clear();
        Combo_ServiceType.SelectedIndex = -1;
        Combo_ServiceType.Focus();
    }

    public void InsertDataToDb()
    {
        var connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LogsDbContext"].ConnectionString;

        try
        {
            using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connection))
            {
                sqlConnection.Open();

                using (var command = new SqlCommand())
                {

                    command.Connection = sqlConnection;
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO dbo.EntryLogs (ServiceType, ServiceIP, Username, Password, OldPassword, Description, CreatedSysUser, Notes) VALUES (@ServiceType, @ServiceIP, @Username, @Password, @OldPassword, @Description, @CreatedSysUser, @Notes)";

                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ServiceType", Combo_ServiceType.SelectedItem.ToString());
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ServiceIP", string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Text_ServiceIP.Text) ? (object)DBNull.Value : Text_ServiceIP.Text);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", Text_Username.Text);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", Text_Password.Text);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OldPassword", Text_OldPassword.Text);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Text_Description.Text) ? (object)DBNull.Value : Text_Description.Text);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreatedSysUser", _currentUserOnApp.GetCurrentUsernameOnApp());
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Notes", string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Text_Notes.Text) ? (object)DBNull.Value : Text_Notes.Text);

                    var result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    // Check Error
                    if (result < 0)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(@"Error inserting data into Database!", @"Error Inserting Data", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel);
                    }

                    MessageBox.Show(@"Record inserted to database!", @"Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    sqlConnection.Close();

                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(@"ERROR: ", e.Message);
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: How big is the data? say you have 200 records, every time you insert a record you can trigger and call a function to update the status.

Comment: no big data just 1 record at a time, is textboxes all data and 1 combobox that inserts into the database. but my goal would be to add a progress bar after I hit the button UPDATE which inserts the texboxes and combobox data to DB.

Comment: If you inserting one record, it should take no more than 20ms. How long it takes in your case?

Comment: Looks like about 20ms to 40ms

Comment: I am not sure if you need to show a progress bar something that is almost instantaneous

Comment: yea I know, but I would like to add because the app will keep growing and eventually will have more data and records to insert, so if now as is simple to add would be great.

Comment: In this event handler, Button_Update_Click, you can show a spinner image[animated gif] instead of progress bar, and then call InsertDataToDB(), after that call returns, you can hide this spinner image.

Answer (score 0):

Use background worker.

```
double perc;
int count = 0;
```

Then add this code before the loop does.

```
count++;

//Create an extension method on this one that only accept up to 100, there's no 101%.

perc = Math.Round((Convert.ToDouble(count) / Convert.ToDouble(overall)) * 100); 
yourbackgroundworker.ReportProgress((int)perc);
```

On ProgressChange:

```
progressbar.value = e.ProgressPercentage;
```

Comment: I will try that and see, also could you add the full backgroundworker?